# Autoextensible/autoallocate confusion

Tags: oracle

In oracle, the extent management clause in [create tablespace](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_7003.htm) has the keyword *autoallocate*. But in the table [dba_data_files](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_3083.htm#REFRN23049) has a column *autoextensible*. Does the keyword in create table space sets this particular column?

**EDIT**

What I am trying to do is reconstruct the "create tablespace" command from an existing database. So need to ascertain if I need to use *autoallocate*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, those things aren't related.

Autoallocate means you're letting the database decide what size extent to 'allocate' for your object and its data.

From the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14231/tspaces.htm) -

> If you expect the tablespace to contain objects of varying sizes
>   requiring many extents with different extent sizes, then AUTOALLOCATE
>   is the best choice. AUTOALLOCATE is also a good choice if it is not
>   important for you to have a lot of control over space allocation and
>   deallocation, because it simplifies tablespace management. Some space
>   may be wasted with this setting, but the benefit of having Oracle
>   Database manage your space most likely outweighs this drawback

Autoextend means the tablespace can grow files on it's own if they get 'full', until they reach a predetermined limit, or optionally 'UNLIMITED.'

Comment: I am trying to create the "create table space" command from an existing database. Where can I find out if a particular table space was created with autoallocate?

Comment: select * from dba_tablespaces where allocation_type = 'SYSTEM'

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is a confution. The *autoallocate* is the property of the TABLESPACE see the [extent_management_clause](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_7003.htm#i2063392), the *autoextensible* is the proparty of a file see the [file_specification](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/clauses004.htm#g1057086) clause (AUTOEXTEND ON)

Here a small example (file name shortened for brevity)

See the relevant data dictionary columns [`dba_tablespaces.ALLOCATION_TYPE`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_4157.htm#REFRN23287) and `dba_data_files.AUTOEXTENSIBLE`

```
CREATE TABLESPACE T1   DATAFILE 'D:\...\T1.DBF' SIZE 1M
   EXTENT MANAGEMENT LOCAL AUTOALLOCATE
 ;



CREATE TABLESPACE T2   DATAFILE 'D:\...\T2.DBF'  SIZE 1M   AUTOEXTEND ON
   EXTENT MANAGEMENT LOCAL  UNIFORM SIZE 128K
 ;

select TABLESPACE_NAME,EXTENT_MANAGEMENT, ALLOCATION_TYPE
from dba_tablespaces where tablespace_name in ('T1','T2');
TABLESPACE_NAME                EXTENT_MAN ALLOCATIO
------------------------------ ---------- ---------
T1                             LOCAL      SYSTEM   
T2                             LOCAL      UNIFORM  

select AUTOEXTENSIBLE,  FILE_NAME from dba_data_files;

AUT FILE_NAME
--- -------------------
NO  T1.DBF
YES T2.DBF
```

Comment: @EdHeal you should check (among other) the columns `EXTENT_MANAGEMENT` and `ALLOCATION_TYPE` in  [DBA_TABLESPACES](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_4157.htm#REFRN23287)